# How to send a clean GraphQL request

Tags: graphql, url-encoding

I'm new to GraphQL. I've created a working schema implementation but my problem is making my API developer friendly. If users want to send the query below it seems very kludgy to ask them to compress it to one line, remove spaces, then urlencode it to fit into a query parameter or even json encoding it as well. Overall, I know this is suppose to be easier than REST so I figure I must be doing something wrong.

**Question**

What are some efficient ways of transforming the following GrapqhQL query into a format that can be transmitted across the internet?

```
 search(firstName:"bob",lastName:"Smith", num: 0, max: 10)
    {
        age, 
        height,
        email,
        country,
        occupation
    }
```

**Problem**

Documentation on the Graphql sites always reference the simplest use-case of a query like { age }. But when it comes to real queries so far this seems uglier than REST.

Answer (score 1):

Your GraphQL syntax is wrong. That is why its not being encoded. If your syntax was right all you need to do is push the whole String into a URL/URI encoder and thats it. Heres the corrected syntax, you're missing brackets.

```
{
 search(firstName:"bob",lastName:"Smith", num: 0, max: 10)
    {
        age, 
        height,
        email,
        country,
        occupation
    }
}
```

Here is some additional documentation with some examples at the bottom
http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-server/requests.html